# Como monitorar um código em C no Linux

Tags: c, linux, desempenho

Eu estava tentando usar top para monitorar a performance dos meus códigos em c, mas quando executo não aparece o programa. Ele está lá só não está visível, ou não dá pra monitorar códigos em c usando o top? O que eu deveria usar para monitorar se o top não funcionar?
O código é esse:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 

int main(){
    struct stat info; 
    pid_t id, filho;
    struct timeval tv1, tv2;
    double t1, t2;

    id = getpid();
    printf("Processo %ld \n", (long)id);

    gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
    lstat("teste", &info);
    gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);

    t1 = (double)(tv1.tv_sec) + (double)(tv1.tv_usec)/ 1000000.00;
    t2 = (double)(tv2.tv_sec) + (double)(tv2.tv_usec)/ 1000000.00;
    printf("\nO tempo de execucao foi %lf\n", (t2 - t1));

    _exit(0);
}
```

Eu uso `gcc -o dados dados.c` para compilar o arquivo. E `./dados` para executar no terminal. No próprio código ele mostra o pid dele e quando eu vou procurar no ps, eu não encontro.

Comment: O programa roda muito rápido para aparecer na lista do top. Quando tu executa o _exit(0) no final o PID morre, não vai mais aparecer no ps nem no top...

Comment: Tu tem alguma dica de como terminar o programa, então?

Comment: Não sei exatamente  o que você quer monitorar, mas de repente essa lib pode te ajudar:

    man getrusage
    
NAME
getrusage -- get information about resource utilization

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/resource.h>

     #define   RUSAGE_SELF     0
     #define   RUSAGE_CHILDREN     -1

Comment: Estou monitorando o tempo de execução, memória utilizada e processamento. O que você me passou só não retorna processamento, mas mesmo assim é de muita ajuda. Se souber algum q faça isso seria muito bom mesmo. Obrigado :)

Comment: De nada. Deixa eu te perguntar. O que você define por "processamento" ? Se for a porcentagem de CPU utilizada, apenas divida o user time pelo real time.

Comment: É isso mesmo. Esses _time_'s eu consigo só usando o comando _time_?

Comment: Vacilo meu. O que tu passou já faz isso. Valeu!

Comment: Eu preciso fundamentar esse teste e eu procurei por aqui e não achei nada onde diga que a porcentagem de CPU é esse cálculo que tu me passou. Onde eu posso achar isso? Obrigado desde, já!

Comment: Achei esse artigo bem interessante (em ingles): http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9001

Uma coisa que tem que ficar clara é que tu vai ter que definir um slot de tempo para calcular a porcentagem de CPU utilizada.

Answer (score 2):

1- Você pode usar o top para monitorar apenas um PID. Descubra o PID do programa como o colega sugeriu:

```
ps -aucx|grep <nome do programa>
```

Eu gosto de utilizar o comando abaixo, pois só lista comandos filhos da SHELL que eu estou usando, logo se você rodou o programa a partir da mesma SHELL, você pode facilmente descobrir o PID dele.:

```
ps -T
```

E para o comando top utilize com o parâmetro -p:

```
top -p <PID>
```

Abaixo há alguns comandos que podem ser utilizados dentro da interface do top:

```
       Global_defaults
          ’A’ - Alt display      Off (full-screen)
        * ’d’ - Delay time       3.0 seconds
          ’I’ - Irix mode        On  (no, ’solaris’ smp)
        * ’p’ - PID monitoring   Off
        * ’s’ - Secure mode      Off (unsecured)
          ’B’ - Bold disable     Off
       Summary_Area_defaults
          ’l’ - Load Avg/Uptime  On  (thus program name)
          ’t’ - Task/Cpu states  On  (1+1 lines, see ’1’)
          ’m’ - Mem/Swap usage   On  (2 lines worth)
          ’1’ - Single Cpu       On  (thus 1 line if smp)
       Task_Area_defaults
          ’b’ - Bold hilite      On  (not ’reverse’)
        * ’c’ - Command line     Off (name, not cmdline)
        * ’H’ - Threads          Off (show all threads)
        * ’i’ - Idle tasks       On  (show all tasks)
          ’R’ - Reverse sort     On  (pids high-to-low)
        * ’S’ - Cumulative time  Off (no, dead children)
          ’x’ - Column hilite    Off (no, sort field)
          ’y’ - Row hilite       On  (yes, running tasks)
          ’z’ - color/mono       Off (no, colors)
```

Se o top mostrar que o seu programa está consumindo 0% de CPU, utilize outros meios para saber o que o processo está fazendo.

2- Se você quiser ver arquivos abertos pelo seu processo: (nome ou pid)

```
lsof -c httpd
lsof -p <PID>
```

3- Processos interagindo com um diretório ou arquivo (por exemplo, seu diretório onde roda o binário)

```
lsof /home/user1/bin
```

4 - Listar todas as chamadas de sistema de um processo

```
strace -p <PID>
```

Comment: Eu estou executando o código exatamente para analisar as chamadas de sistema. Nele, eu consigo chamar o pid do próprio código, mas não consigo monitorar ele. Eu dei uma atualizada na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar os comandos que @cemdorst indicou e executá-lo como se estivesse no terminal através da função popen.

Segue um exemplo para o processo com PID 1234:

```
int main() {
    FILE *stream= popen("top -p 1234", "r");

    if (stream != NULL) {
        int c;

        while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF)
            printf("%c", c);

        pclose(stream);
    }

}
```

Comment: Deu certo pra ti? Conseguisse?